# Create HTML table based on Database Values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a database that has information on actors, roles, and movies. 
On an HTML page I have the user input the first name and last name of an actor.

This form is then submitted to my PHP page where I look through my database, and provide the user with a 3 column html table with the following information: Movie Name the actor has worked in, Role the actor played, and year of movie.

All these information are in separate database tables. Examples of what each table looks like is below:

**actor** table contains:

> 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', and 'gender' stored in the following way - (933,'Actor','Name','M')

**role** table contains:

> 'actor_id', 'movie_id', 'role stored in the following way - (16844,10920,'Role')

**movies** table contains:

> 'id', 'name', 'year', 'rank' stored in the following way - (306032,'Snatch.',2000,7.9)

I have to look through and correlate all the data into a table. This is what I have so far:

```
$sql ="SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM actors";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($row['first_name'] == $firstname && $row['last_name'] == $lastname) {
    $actorID = $row['id'];
    echo "$actorID<br>";
  }

}//end while

$sql2 = "SELECT actor_id, movie_id, role FROM roles";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
  if ($row['actor_id'] == $actorID) {
    $movieID = $row['movie_id'];
    $actRole = $row['role'];
    echo "$movieID <br>";
    echo "$actRole <br>";
  }
} //end while

$sql3 = "SELECT id, name, year FROM movies";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
  if ($row['id'] == $movieID) {
    $movieName = $row['name'];
    $movieYear = $row['year'];
    echo "$movieName <br>";
    echo "$movieYear <br>";
  }
} //end while

echo '
  <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Movie Name </th>
        <th> Actor Role </th>
        <th> Release Date </th> 
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <td>'. $movieName .'</td>
      <td>'. $actRole. '</td>
      <td>'. $movieYear. '</td>
      </tbody>
  </table>'; 


?>
```

My solution works -- just a mediocre way of doing it

Comment: You **really** should not be writing code that relies on `mysql_` functions anymore. The MySQL extension has been deprecated for years and is about to be dropped in the upcoming PHP7 release, which can be release any time now. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). On an up-to-date server, this code has a life span of about a month, after which it will **stop working**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have assign the variables `$firstname` and `$lastname`. Apart from that your `if` condition is wrong true every time.

```
if ($row['first_name'] = $firstname && $row['last_name'] = $lastname) {
```

Should be:

```
if ($row['first_name'] == $firstname && $row['last_name'] == $lastname) {
```

Also check what you want to do with the `echo $row['first_name'][0];`

Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so you better use `mysqli` or PDO.

**EDIT:**

You can select all actors that have play in a movie using the following query. You can adjust to take only the information you need changing `SELECT` clause or using `WHERE`.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT aa.id AS actor_id, aa.first_name, aa.last_name, cc.name, cc.year
    FROM actor AS aa
    INNER JOIN role AS bb
    ON aa.id = bb.actor_id
    INNER JOIN movies AS cc
    ON cc.id = bb.movie_id";
```

**EDIT 2:** (from comments)

You can use the following code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "db_username", "your_password", "your_database");
$query = "
    SELECT aa.id AS actor_id, aa.first_name, aa.last_name, cc.name AS movie_name, cc.year AS release_year
    FROM actor AS aa
    INNER JOIN role AS bb
    ON aa.id = bb.actor_id
    INNER JOIN movies AS cc
    ON cc.id = bb.movie_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

echo '
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Actor id</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Movie name</th>
                <th>Release date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<td>'.$row['actor_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['movie_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['release_year'].'</td>';
}
echo '
        </tbody>
    </table>';
```

Comment: the echo $row['first_name'][0] was just a stupid test I attempted to make to see if im accessing the table right -- clearly im not

Comment: Ok. Try check these and try again.

Comment: worked! I was able to get the actors ID number. How can i make another sql to search through the 'roles' table?

Comment: You can make an SQL query using JOIN to combine the 2 queries. What data are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: well, I need to create an HTML table that has the Movie Name, Role, and year the movie came out with regards to that actor. This is going to involve 3 queries and getting information from each

Comment: what exactly is aa, bb, and cc in this context? Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: It's called alias so you don't have to write again and again the big original names and get confused. Also it distinguishes the columns that have same names among different tables e.g. actor(id), movie(id).

Comment: how would you implement an HTML table to output these values?

Comment: the table is created, however there seems to be no data underneath the values

Comment: Are your tables populated with data?

Comment: Yes they are; please see my updated code. The way i'm going about it is very unprofessional however, it seems to be accessing the right data.

Comment: I can just show you the right way. But of course you are free to choose.

Comment: This is a totally different question on SO.

Comment: Provide a drop down menu (an html "select") that is populated with all the genres.  Allow the user to select a genre and display all the movies (Year, Movie Title) from this particular genre.  The drop down menu MUST be populated by selecting all of the possible genres contained in the database. The 'movies_genres' table has 'movie_id' and 'genre'

Comment: You need AJAX and jQuery for this.

Comment: ill have a go at it myself and post a new question. Thanks for your help today!

Comment: You have to choose the right solutions and not just what it works short termed.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to mark my answer as the accepted once. If you think that the initial question was a "=" in an if condition then it was much more than a simple question.